# Where and how to insert 'try and except' in this code to avoid program crash?

Tags: python

I have this code to download emails and save the text body. It saves the text body as a text file using the text in the subject field as the name of the file. The subject SHOULD basically be a student number + school week number, like:
1234567891week8

```
pathToFiles = '/home/pedro/getEmailtexts/emailTexts17BE/'
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
select_info = server.select_folder('Inbox')
unseenMessages = server.search(['UNSEEN'])
print('Number of unseen messages is ' + str(len(unseenMessages)))

for uid, message_data in server.fetch(unseenMessages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
        print(' message UID is ' + str(uid))
        print(email_message.get('Subject'))
        messageSubject = email_message.get('Subject')
        file = messageSubject + '.txt'
        theFile = open(pathToFiles + file, 'w')
        rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
        message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[uid][b'BODY[]'])
        text =  message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        saveText = text.rstrip()
        theFile.write(saveText)
        theFile.close()
```

However some students, or their email programs, are putting something weird in the subject field, causing a breakdown. Here is a sample output from my bash terminal:

```
1725010108week8
message UID is 33
1725010135week8
message UID is 34
1725010126 week8
message UID is 35
������������������1725010118week8
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./getAnswersFromEmail17BEv2.py", line 45, in <module>
file = messageSubject + '.txt'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Header' and 'str'
pedro@pedro-newssd:~/getEmailtexts/python$
```

I have to go to the email, delete the offending email, and start again.

I think I may be able to insert a try ... except ... in there somehow, but I can't see exactly how. Or maybe there is some other way to deal with a dodgy subject

Do you have any tips for an amateur on how to get round this? How to make the program go to the next email on this kind of error?

Comment: hmm, interesting.  have you tried `messageSubject=str(email_message.get('Subject'))` ?

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be converting the `messageSubject` variable to a string.

i.e

`file = str(messageSubject) + '.txt'`

To use the try except clause, the following snippet will allow the code to move onto the next email if it cannot create the `file` variable for the email

```
try:
    file = messageSubject + '.txt'
except TypeError:
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try your first suggestion first. Tonight at 6pm is the deadline for this weeks homework for 18BE classes. I've changed the code as you suggested. I'll let you know how it goes! If I still get problems, I'll try your second suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@ Alexis Lucattini: Thank you very much!

This solved crazy subject problems:

```
messageSubject = str(email_message.get('Subject'))
```

Then I got " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_payload'"

In the end, I used both suggestions.

At least 1 student must have sent an empty email, which caused problems like this:

```
UID is 421
1825010336week8
Message subject is 1825010336week8
UID is 424
1825010334Week
Message subject is 1825010334Week
UID is 425
=?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDIzNyDA7s7Ex78=?=
Message subject is =?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDIzNyDA7s7Ex78=?=
UID is 426
=?gb18030?B?ufnT7ubDIDE4MjUwMTAyNDQ=?=
Message subject is =?gb18030?B?ufnT7ubDIDE4MjUwMTAyNDQ=?=
UID is 430
=?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDExMyxBLEIsQSxCLEEsQyxELEcsQSxD?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEYsSCxBLEQsQixBLEgsRyxDLEEsQSxCLEEsQSxC?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEIsRixELEosRSxBLEcsQyxILEmBMIQyCgoK?=
Message subject is =?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDExMyxBLEIsQSxCLEEsQyxELEcsQSxD?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEYsSCxBLEQsQixBLEgsRyxDLEEsQSxCLEEsQSxC?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEIsRixELEosRSxBLEcsQyxILEmBMIQyCgoK?=
UID is 431
=?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDEzMSxBLEIsQSxCLEEsQyxELEcsQSxD?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEYsSCxBLEQsQixBLEgsRyxDLEEsQSxCLEEsQSxC?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEIsRixELEosRSxBLEksQyxILEcKCgo=?=
Message subject is =?gb18030?B?MTgyNTAxMDEzMSxBLEIsQSxCLEEsQyxELEcsQSxD?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEYsSCxBLEQsQixBLEgsRyxDLEEsQSxCLEEsQSxC?=
 =?gb18030?B?LEIsRixELEosRSxBLEksQyxILEcKCgo=?=
UID is 432
1825010207week8
Message subject is 1825010207week8
UID is 434
������������������1825010136week7
Message subject is ������������������1825010136week7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getAnswersFromEmail18BEv2.py", line 52, in <module>
    text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_payload'
pedro@pedro-newssd:~/getEmailtexts/python$ ^C
pedro@pedro-newssd:~/getEmailtexts/python$
```

So I put a try except in for that error:

```
for uid, message_data in server.fetch(unseenMessages, 'RFC822').items():
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
        print('UID is ' + str(uid))
        print(email_message.get('Subject'))
        messageSubject = str(email_message.get('Subject'))
        print('Message subject is ' + messageSubject)
        if messageSubject == None:
            messageSubject = 'idiot'
        file = messageSubject + '.txt'
        theFile = open(pathToFiles + file, 'w')
        rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
        try:
            message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[uid][b'BODY[]'])
            text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
            saveText = text.rstrip()
            theFile.write(saveText)
            theFile.close()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
```

After that, all emails downloaded without a problem.
That is good, because now I can use this routine and the routine which marks the answers and writes the scores to an Excel file all together in 1 program.

Thanks for the advice!